# Оптимальная настройка image-min в Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, изображения

Подскажите какие должны быть настройки у **image-min** и его плагинов через **Gulp**, чтобы уровень сжатия картинок (***png, jpg***) был приближен к сжатию в **Tinypng** ?

Вот код, который на данный момент у меня есть:

```
gulp.task("images", function () {
    return gulp.src("Full/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)")
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            progressive: true,
            imageminSvgo: {removeViewBox: false, cleanupAttrs: false},

            use: [
                    imageminPngquant({
                        verbose: "true",
                        quality: '50-65',
                        speed: 1
                    }),
                    imageminMozjpeg({
                        progressive: true
                    })
                ]
            })
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("Clean/img"));
});
```

И сжатие картинок происходит в совсем малом проценте от исходника.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать [gulp-tinypng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tinypng), сжимает картинки, используя tinyPng:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-tinypng');

gulp.task('tinypng', function () {
    gulp.src('src/image.png')
        .pipe(tingpng('API_KEY'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: А что значит 'API_KEY` ? я так понимаю это платное удовольствие ?
Увидел, там только 500 картинок можно сделать.. а непосредственно этими плагинами нельзя полноценно на таком уровне сжимать ?